# How much info does the -g GCC compile option provide?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, compilation

I need to debug a program. For several reasons it is convenient that someone else takes a look at it. However, the code is sensitive and I need to limit the amount of exposure I give to the code itself to the person helping with debugging.

I am considering compiling using the -g option,  so that the person can use gdb.

However, I am not familiar with the amount of information that using the -g option will provide. I want the person helping me to debug to say something like "your coffee gets stuck in line 573", but I don't want that person to be able to reverse engineer the source code.

What is the additional information included in the binary file and accessible using gdb after compiling with the -g option?

Comment: Go through this link : 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options

Comment: Remind me not to take the task from you.  They'll need to see the source code to be able to make effective use of GDB.  You can find out where the problem is by line number more effectively than they can if they can't see the source.  You're trying to make them run blindfolded.  It isn't sensible.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the `-g` option adds information about line numbers and variable names to the object file, so that the debugger can display the source code.

Comment: if the debugger is `gdb`, then should use `-ggdb` rather than `-g` so the debugger has the maximum information available (like the internals of structs, etc etc etc